# Accessing Pattern library in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, spacy, text-analysis

My base environment in Python 3.7. I created a new environment called Python27 (which is Python 2.7 version as I want it for Text Analytics) and is my current environment. I activated it using the command `activate Python27`. So, the top left corner in spyder shows as Spyder(Python 2.7)

I installed Pattern Library using `pip install pattern` and it got successfully installed after I resolved the C1083 error. Now I am having issues accessing it in Spyder when I type `from pattern.en import suggest` I get the error

> ImportError: No module named pattern.en

The same issue is with spacy library. Moreover, I cant see the libraries Pattern and Spacy in `conda list`.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you install this package while having the environment activated?

Comment: Yes, I activated the virtual environment (Python27) and then installed the Pattern library.